# Looking for a regex to remove text from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove some text from a big string with start and end label. For example:

```
...
// THIS IS START
..
..
// THIS IS END
...
```

Above text is saved in an variable. And I need to remove all texts start with `// THIS IS START` to `// THIS IS END`. I know that I can remove them by split the string into lines and parse them line by line. But I am looking for a better solution. Whether I can use `regex` to achieve this? The difficult part for me is to use variables for start/end labels.

Comment: For your last edit please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 1):

Use `.replace` to search for `THIS IS START`, *lazy*-repeat any character, up until `THIS IS END`:

```js
const str = `...
// THIS IS START
..
foo
..
// THIS IS END
...
between
...
// THIS IS START
..
bar
..
// THIS IS END`;
console.log(str.replace(/(\/\/ THIS IS START)[\s\S]+?(\/\/ THIS IS END)/g, '$1\n$2'));
```

If you don't want to include the `//` lines either, then don't bother capturing them, and replace with the empty string:

```js
const str = `...
// THIS IS START
..
foo
..
// THIS IS END
...
between
...
// THIS IS START
..
bar
..
// THIS IS END`;
console.log(str.replace(/\s\/\/ THIS IS START[\s\S]+?\/\/ THIS IS END/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly simple case. You need to mask your `/` and make sure to match the "shortest possible" string with the `[^]*?` expression (`.*?` does not allow newlines!) between the start and end labels, but otherwise it is straightforward.

**Edited**, (after hint from @revo):

```
string.replace(/\/\/ THIS IS START[^]*?\/\/ THIS IS END/g,'')
```

The character class `[^]` allows *all* characters, including newlines etc.

Comment: You probably want to replace `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`.

Comment: Ahh, yes, of course, thanks for mentioning it! I missed that point. I simply forgot to take care of the line breaks :D ...

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be (with gs option)

```
var str = `
// THIS IS START
..
// THIS IS END`;
console.log(str.replace(/\/\/ THIS IS START\n(.+)\/\/ THIS IS END/gs, "$1"));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m8hd1au6/19/

Comment: FYI, `s` is an extension of ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: Thanks how can I make the start and end to be variables?